# Horizontal Scroll don't work, JList

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jlist, border-layout

I have list, table and group of buttons. For example. So table will be on the center and list on the BorderLayout.WEST, etc

I think I really do not understand something, because when I start simple code below there is no horizontal scroll bar. But I need it when some element in JList is visible only a part.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.*;
public class ListDemo {

private JFrame frame;

private JPanel mainPanel;

public ListDemo() {

    createPartControl();
}

private void createPartControl() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setTitle("JList Demo");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    createMainPanel();

    frame.add(mainPanel);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

private void createMainPanel() {
    mainPanel = new JPanel();
    mainPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    String[] words = { "Word1", "Word2", "Word2", "Word4", "Word5", "very long worddddddddddddddd" };
    JList<String> list = new JList<>(words);
    // list.setFixedCellWidth(100);
    JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(list);
    // pane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
    mainPanel.add(pane, BorderLayout.WEST);

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new ListDemo();
}}
```

I tried fixed width method in JList, but it's not work.

Comment: I think the main problem has to do with the use of compounding panels, the `JScrollPane` in the `mainPane` which is put in the `contentPane`.  Why do you need to have so many panels? Also, adding the `ScrollPane` to the `WEST` position of any panel results in the same outcome, so I might be a side effect of how `BorderLayout` treats those components

Comment: @MadProgrammer many panels? I want to add for example `JTable` in `BorderLayout.CENTER`, and `JList` on the `WEST`. I have screen what I need. It is `JTree` in eclipse, but when I changed width  this panel for min, horizontal scrollbar was created http://i.imgur.com/1PxEoeQ.jpg In eclipse seems JTree is on the `WEST` or I'am wrong?

Comment: The `WEST` position may ONLY honor the preferred size of the component, it may NEVER decrease the size of the component beyond this requirement, meaning that the `JScrollPane` will never need the horizontal scroll bars.  You might have better luck with `GridBagLayout`

Answer (score 0):

You need to place the mainPanel into a JScrollPane as well before adding to the Frame:

```
frame.add(new JScrollPane(mainPanel));
```

Comment: I tried but it's not what I need. I need something like on this image http://i.imgur.com/1PxEoeQ.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the scrollpane to the center of the BorderLayout's panel:

```
mainPanel.add(pane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

If you need it to the west, use nested panels.